# Importing functions from different packet

Tags: python, import, pcap, sys, modulenotfounderror

I'm studying PCAP certificate and I have one question about how import functions from other packets whose location is different to the current directory.

Theory says that I have to do the next code:

```
path.append('..\\packages')

import extra.iota

print(extra.iota.funI())
```

The directories of that example are the next:
[image]

**Previous code is running on main.py, inside progs folder**

So, I try it in the next order:

1. I download extra folder in a .zip. which I descompress and move to my main folder called PCAP.
2. So, now I have in PCAP two folders: pyWorks, when I run my examples or exercises and pyImport when I have 'extra' folder.
3. I try just like the example shows although I change obviously 'packages' for 'pyImport' which is the folder where is located extra and the others.

This is my code:

```
from sys import path

path.append('..\\pyImport')

**import extra.iota**

print(extra.iota.FunI())
```

pyImport is the folder where extra is located, same as packages contains extra by the theory but I have an **ModuleNotFoundError** cause No module called extra in the bold line inside the code.
It can be that I'm running my code on macOS or something?

What's happening??

Answer (score 0):

Okey my code started to run if I put the complete directories route or if I put:

```
path.append('./pyImport')
#instead of:
path.append('..\\pyImport')
```

It was because I was running my code from macOS.